# Converting <-1;1> to x y coordinations

Tags: c#, xna, hlsl

I need to convert <-1;1> to x y coordinations to draw a triangle on screen.

```
vertices[0].Position = new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0f);
```

How can I convert x y to that float number precisely?

Comment: What is <-1;1> for kind of type? Is it a string? And why does -1;1 convert to -0.5, -0.5, 0 ?

Comment: Rather than manually calculating positions/offsets by hand (read: in software), properly set your view/projection/model matrix to do the conversation for you.

Comment: I am using 2d textures and sorry for not being clearly, it meant that x y must be between -1 to 1 and I want to use the full coordinations

Comment: Use a projection matrix